# svn accept doesn't fix tree conflict

Tags: svn

I have the following SVN folder structure:

```
/myproject
    /branches
        /branch1
        /branch2
    /tags
    /trunk
```

branch1 and branch2 were created at different times using an svn copy:

```
svn copy /trunk /branches/branch1 (r2918)
svn copy /trunk /branches/branch2 (r3074)
```

branch2 has now been merged back to the trunk (r3119). So, I need to get the changes from branch2 into branch1. To do that, I am trying an automated sync merge:

```
cd /myproject/branches/branch1
svn merge --dry-run ^/trunk
```

It looks good except for 2 tree conflicts:

```
--- Merging r2917 through r3141 into '.':
C    file1.zip
C    file2.txt
U    file3.docx
U    file4.xlsx
U    file5.pdf
U    file6.png
 U   .
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 2
```

EDIT: My understanding from the SVN red-bean is that someone would have had to move or delete file1.zip and file2.txt from the trunk in order for these tree conflicts to occur. But, nothing like that has happened in the trunk, and nothing like that happened during the merge of branch2.

I've tried svn cleanup, svn update, svn resolve and svn merge with the --accept flag, but nothing has actually resolved the tree conflicts. So, I'm not sure what to do next. I'm using mac terminal commanding instead of Tortoise on Windows.

I'm looking to get better at svn in general. I've tried the SVN red-bean, but it confuses me sometimes. I'm looking for something similar to w3schools where it has you start at a beginning point, and then build onto your own work as you learn. Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the --dry-run flag does not allow you walk through the process of resolving conflicts. I never knew this, but it would've saved me hours and hours if I had. I removed the --dry-run flag in my merge command in order to get the options to resolve the conflicts for file1.zip and file2.txt:

```
cd /myproject/branches/branch1
svn merge ^/trunk
```

Then, I was able to see the prompts for resolving the tree conflicts:

```
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r2917 through r3141 into '.':
 G   .
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 2
Merge conflict discovered in binary file 'config_files/MDM_CFG.zip'.
Select: (p) Postpone, (mf) Mark as resolved, (tf) Accept incoming: tf
Merge conflicts in 'config_files/MDM_CFG.zip' marked as resolved.
Merge conflict discovered in file 'config_files/MDM_CFG.zip.sha1'.
Select: (p) Postpone, (df) Show diff, (e) Edit file, (m) Merge,
        (s) Show all options:
```

I chose tf (theirs-full) for both, the tree conflicts were resolved, and my merge was committed.

Comment: *Text* conflict **is not** *tree* conflict. With **real** tree conflict you'll cry a lot more